# How to use a regular expression in Dart to find substring within string

Tags: regex, dart

I have a problem with the regular expression to look for a substring within a string.

```
void main(){

  var string = "HOLA MUNDO";

  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r'/MUNDO/',caseSensitive: false,);
  exp.hasMatch(string)==true? print('Match'): print('nope');


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the `/` at the front of the RegExp works in Dart (or, at least not the way you may have intended).  Try `RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"MUNDO", caseSensitive: false);`.  Your regex is failing because it tries to match a literal '/' in the string.